# Excel VBA - Copy and Paste Loop in VBA based on cell value

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to come up with a macro that checks if any numeral value exists in a cell.  If a numeral value exists, copy a portion of that row and paste it into another worksheet within the same spreadsheet.

Sheet1 is the sheet that has all my data in it.  I am trying to look in column R if there is any values in it.  If it does, copy that cell and the four adjacent cells to the left of it and paste it into Sheet2.

This is what I have come up with so far based on mish-mashing other people's code though it only does a part of what I want.  It just copies part of a row then pastes it into another worksheet but it does not check column R for a value first.  It just copies and pastes regardless and does not move onto the next row once it has done that.  I need it to continue onto the next row to continue looking:

```
Sub Paste_Value_Test()

Dim c As Range
Dim IRow As Long, lastrow As Long
Dim rSource As Range
Dim wsI As Worksheet, wsO As Worksheet

On Error GoTo Whoa

'~~> Sheet Where values needs to be checked
Set wsI = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
'~~> Output sheet
Set wsO = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With wsI
    '~~> Find Last Row which has data in Col O to R
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
        lastrow = .Columns("O:R").Find(What:="*", _
                      After:=.Range("O3"), _
                      Lookat:=xlPart, _
                      LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                      SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                      SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                      MatchCase:=False).Row
    Else
        lastrow = 1
    End If

    '~~> Set you input range
    Set rSource = .Range("R" & lastrow)

    '~~> Search for the cell which has "L" and then copy it across to sheet1
    For Each c In rSource
    Debug.Print cValue
        If c.Value > "0" Then
            .Range("O" & c.Row & ":R" & c.Row).Copy
            wsO.Cells(5 + IRow, 12).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            IRow = IRow + 1
        End If
    Next
End With

LetsContinue:
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Exit Sub
Whoa:
MsgBox Err.Description
Resume LetsContinue
End Sub
```

Comment: " It just copies part of a row then pastes it into another worksheet" - Isn't that what you want? Or does it not copy all of what you're expecting? Can you clarify the issue?

Comment: @BruceWayne it's copying what I am expecting but it is copying and pasting it indiscriminately and does not continue checking to the next row afterwards.  I need Excel to check if there is a value in Column R first then copy and paste if a value exists.  If not, continue down the next row.  I apologize for not being clear, I will edit now.

Comment: So you are saying that this test is not functioning properly? If c.Value > "0" Then

Comment: Check your variable declaration. You set `wsI` to `Sheet2`, but I think you need to switch those around.  You're looping through a range on Sheet2, and copying the range on `Sheet2`. Don't you want that to be Sheet1?

Comment: @TheTTGGuy it appears that it is not functioning properly.  There is no value in column R yet Excel will still copy the row and paste it into the Sheet2.

Comment: Umm - `Set rSource = .Range("R" & lastrow)` - that is setting `rSource` to the **single** cell which is the last cell in column R, so there isn't much point in then doing a `For Each c In rSource`, you may as well just `Set c = .Range("R" & lastrow)`

Comment: Add a line in the code above that: debug.print c.Value

Comment: @BruceWayne You are correct - I changed the sheet names initially for privacy and looks like I got them mixed up.  Thank you for pointing that one out

Comment: And, of course, you have hard-coded the copy to always copy the three cells in columns O, P and Q of row 3.

Comment: To piggy back off @YowE3K - Try `.Range("O" & c.row & ":Q" & c.row).Copy`

Comment: @YowE3K I will change the first suggestion you made.  How should I change the copy function to copy the cells adjacent to the the current cell that is being checked for an existing value (in Column R)?

Comment: @BruceWayne I think it probably needs to be column N to R based on the OP's statement "copy that cell and the four adjacent cells to the left of it" but, yeah, that looks a lot more sensible.

Comment: Don't change things based on my first suggestion - that was just pointing out that you are only processing **one** cell.  I suspect (but don't understand the question enough to be sure) that you really meant to use `Set rSource = .Range("R1:R" & lastRow)`.

Comment: @YowE3K I made the change to the .Range command.  It looks like that's exactly what I needed! Is there a way to make this a loop now so that once it pastes, it will continue looking down the next row?

Comment: @BruceWayne I made the change you suggested to the Range command and it works exactly like I want it to.  Do you know how to turn this into a loop now so that it will continue looking onto the next row afterwards?

Comment: See my previous comment. (It was probably written while you were writing your comment, so you probably didn't see it.)

Comment: @YowE3K I apologize but I am not well versed in VBA - I have only started to teach myself the basics so I'm not sure if I should have used that one.  It was just something I pulled from someone else's code.  I made the change to use      Set rSource = .Range("R1:R" & lastRow) to see what happens and it appears that nothing changed when I run the macro

Comment: Do you still have the `For Each c In rSource` loop after the `Set rSource = .Range("R1:R" & lastRow)` statement?

Comment: @YowE3K Yes I do still have     >For Each c In rSource loop after the statement.  It looks like it only stops after the first copy+paste.  If I change Set rSource = .Range("R1:R" & lastRow) to be R7:R, it will copy+paste the value properly.  Then if I change it to R8:R, it will copy+paste the next value right under properly which is what I want.  But for some reason, it will not automatically cycle past that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is some code which hopefully achieves what I **think** you are trying to do.  I have included comments throughout stating what I changed:

```
Sub Paste_Value_Test()

    Dim c As Range
    Dim IRow As Long, lastrow As Long
    Dim rSource As Range
    Dim wsI As Worksheet, wsO As Worksheet

    On Error GoTo Whoa

    '~~> Sheet Where values needs to be checked
    Set wsI = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    '~~> Output sheet
    Set wsO = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With wsI
        '~~> Find Last Row which has data in Col O to R
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
            'You specified "After" to be cell O3.  This means a match will
            '  occur on row 2 if cell R2 (or O2 or P2) has something in it
            '  because cell R2 is the cell "after" O3 when
            '  "SearchDirection:=xlPrevious"

            '             After:=.Range("O3"), _

            lastrow = .Columns("O:R").Find(What:="*", _
                          After:=.Range("O1"), _
                          Lookat:=xlPart, _
                          LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                          SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                          SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                          MatchCase:=False).Row
        Else
            lastrow = 1
        End If

        'This was only referring to the single cell in column R on the
        '  last row (in columns O:R)
        'Set rSource = .Range("R" & lastrow)
        'Create a range referring to everything in column R, from row 1
        '  down to the "last row"
        Set rSource = .Range("R1:R" & lastrow)

        'This comment doesn't seem to reflect what the code was doing, or what the
        'question said
        '~~> Search for the cell which has "L" and then copy it across to sheet1
        For Each c In rSource
            'This is printing the variable "cValue", which has never been set
            'Debug.Print cValue
            'It was probably meant to be
            Debug.Print c.Value
            'This was testing whether the value in the cell was
            '  greater than the string "0"
            'So the following values would be > "0"
            '  ABC
            '  54
            '  ;asd
            'And the following values would not be > "0"
            '  (ABC)
            '  $523   (assuming that was as text, and not just 523 formatted as currency)
            'If c.Value > "0" Then
            'I suspect you are trying to test whether the cell is numeric
            '  and greater than 0
            If IsNumeric(c.Value) Then
                If c.Value > 0 Then
                    'This is only copying the cell and the *three* cells
                    ' to the left of it
                    '.Range("O" & c.Row & ":R" & c.Row).Copy
                    'This will copy the cell and the *four* cells
                    ' to the left of it
                    '.Range("N" & c.Row & ":R" & c.Row).Copy
                    'wsO.Cells(5 + IRow, 12).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                    'But this would avoid the use of copy/paste
                    wsO.Cells(5 + IRow, 12).Resize(1, 5).Value = _
                         .Range("N" & c.Row & ":R" & c.Row).Value
                    IRow = IRow + 1
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End With

LetsContinue:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume LetsContinue
End Sub
```

Comment: To my amateur eyes, this code looks like it should do what I want it to but when I run the macro, it looks like nothing happens.  I'm not quite sure what I'm missing here...May I ask you to try the macro out?

Comment: @JDoe Yes, works for me - you may need to include a screenshot of your data into the question (or single-step through the code to see what it is doing)

Comment: I have created a new worksheet with example data that mirrors the layout of my data.  Here it is: https://imgur.com/a/Zjx9z .  I ran the code and it appears nothing happens.  However when I remove row 1 with the words TEST, it will copy+paste row 3 (row that starts with jan) then stop.  I will need to keep row 1 in tact so my data that needs to be copy+pasted actually starts on row 3

Comment: @JDoe You have data in O1:R2, so that is confusing your `Find` (because it finds the data in R2 and therefore sets `lastrow` to 2) - therefore it isn't copying anything at all.  I'll edit the answer to change `"O3"` to `"O1"`.

Comment: you solved it!  Thank you so so so much.  It is perfect now.  I have another question if it is appropriate to ask.  Is there a way I can can pull data from column J and place specific text with it then paste it into the next worksheet alongside those values we just pasted before?

Comment: If you look at the line saying `wsO.Cells(5 + IRow, 12).Resize(1, 5).Value = .Range("N" & c.Row & ":R" & c.Row).Value`, you should be able to easily put another line straight after it changing "12" to whatever column you want to store the value in, changing the number of columns you want to process from "5" to "1", and changing `"N" & c.Row & ":R" & c.Row` to `"J" & c.Row & ":J" & c.Row`  (or it can be simplified to, for example, `wsO.Cells(5 + IRow, 17).Value = .Range("J" & c.Row).Value`)

Comment: that is just about what I needed to the T.  Just one more thing to question - is there a code I can insert into that that lets me combine words with the value in column J then paste it without affecting column J?  For example, J1 has value "123".  I want to be able to add the words "ID Number #" right before it then have Excel paste "ID Number #123".  All the while J1 will still say just "123" at the end of the day.

Comment: You have to stop asking questions and do some research yourself!  (But, FWIW, to concatenate two strings you can use the `&` operator - so `wsO.Cells(5 + IRow, 17).Value =  "ID Number #" & .Range("J" & c.Row).Value` )

Comment: I swear I did exactly that before and it didn't work!  But I tried just now and it worked....haha...Thank you so much for all your help sir.  It does not go unappreciated :)