# vba copy and paste loop based on list

Tags: excel, vba, list, loops, copy-paste

I am trying to write a macro that will copy and paste a specific set of cells based on a list on another worksheet. I have a set of cells A2:E7 that need to be copied down to a new blank row each time a new name on the list changes until the end of the list. A2 will be populated by each name on the list until a blank cell is encountered on the list.

Formulas to copy and paste loop with descriptions on a tab named Summary

[image]

The list starts at B2 on a separate tab named Master

[image]

Comment: Can you post the code you have so far?

Comment: I am new to VBA so I currently do not have any code. I have been looking for something similar to play around with but nothing has been helpful in the exact need I have.

Comment: *Welcome to [so]!* A good place to start would be [googling the title of your question](https://www.google.com/search?q=vba+copy+and+paste+loop+based+on+list) which has several matches to your question almost word-for-word. Check out the [tour] (you'll earn your 1st badge!) This is a site where programmers *write their own code* and share a ***specific* problem** after trying to solve it on their own. See the [help/on-topic] for more information about what's on topic on this site and how to create a **[mcve]**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel VBA - Copy and Paste Loop in VBA based on cell value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48289310/excel-vba-copy-and-paste-loop-in-vba-based-on-cell-value)

Comment: Start by recording a macro of you actually doing it... then review the code and modify... @ChadB

Answer (score 0):

I believe the below should work, to be safe I would delete the data in the Medina-15-17, rows 11 on:

```
'The 2 refers to column "B" on the Master worksheet, change to 1 if in column "A"
summary_row = Worksheets("Master").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

For Each cell In Worksheets("Master").Range("B2:B" & summary_row)
    'this gets a new row count for each iteration 
    temp_row = Worksheets("Summary").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    With Worksheets("Summary")
        'this copy/pastes the templated range 
        .Range("A1:E7").Copy Range("A" & temp_row + 2)

        'this inserts, from the master worksheet, the title 
        .Range("A" & temp_row + 2).Value = cell
    End With
Next cell
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much. I had to modify the name being put in from .Range("A" & temp_row + 2).Value = cell to .Range("A" & temp_row + 3).Value = cell to have the name be put in the correct cell